# if Input: 8-e Expected Output: 2|4|6|8

Tags: javascript

Question 2: The input consist of a string, "o" represents odd number, "e" represents even number to be printed

Example 1.

Input: 8-e

Expected Output: 2|4|6|8

Example 2.

Input: 6-o

Expected Output: 1|3|5

Example 3.

Input: 1-o

Expected Output: 1

if have tried with for loop, but I'am a beginner so I'am confused with(-e)

```
const evenOdd = (number) => {
let evenvalue = [];
let oddValue=[];
for(let i =0; i<=number; i++){
if(number%i==0)
    evenvalue.push(i);
console.log(evenvalue);
}if(number%i!=0){
    oddValue.push(i);
console.log(oddValue);
}

};

evenOdd(9);
```

Comment: You have to parse your string first. You could use a regex or simply extract the two last characters of your string.

Comment: I don't see any reason for downvote here, op posted his efforts and also very clear about what he's trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

You could take a `while` statement and get a start value of one plus an offset of one if the wanted type is even. Then iterate and add the value to the result set until the value is greater than the maximum value.

```js
function fn(request) {
    var [max, type] = request.split('-'),
        i = 1 + (type === 'e'),
        result = [];

    while (i <= max) {
        result.push(i);
        i += 2;
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(...fn('8-e'));
console.log(...fn('6-o'));
console.log(...fn('1-o'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split on `-` and add based on type add values upto the number

- Split the given input by `-`, first value represents max number and second represents it's type
- Check the type if it is even add the even values start from `2` and upto to the max number else start from 1, and join them with `|` in the end

```js
let func = (input) => {
  let [num, type] = input.split('-')
  let arr = []
  let i = 1 + (type === 'e')
  while (i <= num) {
      arr.push(i)
      i += 2
  }
  return arr.join('|')
}

console.log(func('8-e'))
console.log(func('1-o'))
console.log(func('6-o'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to extract the letter and the number from you string first. One easy way to do that :

```
const evenOdd = (s) => {
  let odd = s.length-1 ==='o';
  let number = Number(s.substring(0, s.length-2));
  let evenvalue = [];
  ...
  if(odd){...} else {...}
};
```

You could also use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or if the pattern was more complicated, a [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, don't supply a number to the function, supply a string and then parse the string. That is, don't try and give the function `9-e`, give it `'9-e'`.

- Get the parts of the input by splitting on `-`.
- Turn the number into a number.
- Give 0 for even, 1 for odd (x % 2 is 0 for even number, 1 for odd).
- Build the results.

```js
function listNumbers(constraint)
{
  const parts = constraint.split('-');
  const number = Number(parts[0]);
  const numberType = parts[1] === 'e' ? 0:1;
  let result = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= number; i++)
  {
    if(i%2 === numberType)
    {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(listNumbers('8-e'));
```

Or if you want make the code look clever:

```js
function listNumbers(constraint)
{
  const parts = constraint.split('-');
  const number = Number(parts[0]);
  const numberType = parts[1] === 'e' ? 0:1;
  return Array.from(Array(number), (x,i) => i + 1 ).filter(x => x%2 == numberType);
}

console.log(listNumbers('8-e'));
```